# Need help on converting an excel financial formula to apex code

Tags: apex, formula

I have a requirement wherein I have to create payment schedules for the duration of the loan term. So the formula that I received from the finance team is below

```
(((1)-(1/((1+(3%/12))^(Term-1))))/(3%/12)*MonthlyPayment)+MonthlyPayment+(ResidualValue/((1+(3%/12))^Term))
```

I am trying to convert this to apex because I have to keep decrementing the term value and create those many schedules.

I have tried the below logic by looping over the term length but it is nowhere near to the excel calculations.

```
Decimal d1 = (1 + ((3/100) / 12));
Decimal d2 = term - i;

Decimal result = (((1) - (1 / Math.pow((d1), (d2)))) / (0.03 / 12) * monthlyPayment) + monthlyPayment + (residualValue / Math.pow((d1), d2));
```

Please can someone help on this and provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The portion of the expression `(ResidualValue/((1+(3%/12))^Term))`

you have coded as

```
(residualValue / Math.pow((d1), d2)
```

but d2 = `term -i` and the excel formula wants simply `term`

so you need

```
(residualValue / Math.pow((d1), term)
```

Note these kind of problems are best solved by step-wise reduction; matching each piece of the excel formula to your apex and then building as you go

Comment: Also, breaking the excel formula onto multiple lines in, say, notepad (and also indenting an extra level every time you encounter an open paren) is going to make it much easier for you to deconstruct and reconstruct it. Our puny human brains don't do very well with a sea of parenthesis.

Comment: Oh sorry for the typo above, but in the code I have used term instead of term - i